# Update Un-updatable view through Instead-Of Triggers with "FOR UPDATE"-cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

**Context of the problem:** I'm working on a way to both capture all changes to a table as well as to only expose certain rows to any procedures or cursors selecting the data. For this purpose I create the table from the table definition in another schema (let call it schema A) and also create a view in this schema that exposes data from the newly created table in schema A, as well as the original one in schema B. (using a UNION)

[image: Simplified design]

Not shown here but also included is the ability to "switch on/off" the tables in either schema A or B as well as to limit the visible data from schema A through global context variables. In the instead-of trigger the DML is captured and any changes are logged in logging-tables.

The actual functions or procedures processing the data are already in place and I cannot modify those. These functions are designed to access the tables in schema B directly.

This set-up works quite well and I'm able to capture all data changes this way in the way I wanted. However one issue remains. Whenever a procedure contains a cursor with the `FOR UPDATE` option, the procedure fails with `ORA-02014: Cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.`.

The view is not an updatable view because of the UNION-construction. However, I can capture all other updates with an Instead-Of-Trigger.

**Actual question:** Is there a way to make this design (the VIEW) work even when using `FOR UPDATE` cursors? Perhaps I could supply the ROWID myself or trick the cursor in some way?

(Note, the UNION in the view doesn't actually merge the datasets of the 2 tables, since it switches to either table in schema A ór B, one of the two `SELECT ... FROM [A.table] UNION SELECT ... FROM [B.Table]` will always return 0 rows.)

Comment: Good question. The only suggestion I can offer is an alternative architecture, using synonym switching instead of union-all views: http://tylermuth.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/synonym-switching-technique-and-tools/